# Adding drop down list from tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I ve just started to learn ASP.Net technology and stopped on interesting tutorial from Microsoft. 
Here is the [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  There is a part where they adding and populate drop down list and I cant understand how. When I am doing exactly as they do I dont get that drop down list. Please explain me is there everything ok with that part and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the tutorial is ok or I got it to work at some point. Without the appropriate snippet of your code to compare, there's not much else anyone can do to answer your question though.

Comment: I did just absolutely the same as in that tutorial.. I am just thinking that they missed part with that drop down list in view. So there is no reason to add the same code i think :/

Comment: you never know what you might have copied and pasted incorrectly.. the smallest silliest errors can be the hardest to notice!

Comment: I understand that perfectly.. all i ask is just to look at that tutorial part and find the way they add a drop down list. There is no code for that, or I just cant find :(

Comment: If you think their tutorial is wrong, documentate yourself from other sources and compare the results of your research with the code you deem faulty. Stack Overflow isn't a place where you go asking just about anything that comes to mind.

Comment: The dropdownlist is created in the method PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList() and is then assigned to a viewbag value for passing to the View.  You should be able to use the debugger to ascertain that the selectlist is created and if that's ok, then the issue could be in the View.  Can you see where the ViewBag value is accessed in the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Html.DropDownList()` is a little bit special. You can either pass it a parameter value implicitly or explicitly.

In the tutorial, they are doing it implicitly by calling the helper with the name of the model property, like so:

```
<div class="editor-field"> 
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", String.Empty) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID) 
</div>
```

By doing it implicitly, the HTML-helper will look in the `ViewBag` for an object with the same name. And, as you can see in the `PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()` method they are doing exactly that (last line):

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
{
    var departmentsQuery = from d in db.Departments
                           orderby d.Name
                           select d;
    ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "DepartmentID", "Name", selectedDepartment);
}
```

In [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc), the `@Html.DropDownList()` helper is explained in more detail.